# $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: general-topology, matrices, compactness

If we consider $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ as a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the usual topology and want to know if it compact or not then if we could show that it was not closed then we would know that it is not compact. I know we can do this by consider the map $\det:GL(2,\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ and note that the image is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ which is open. But could we instead just consider the sequence:

$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \left ( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{a} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{a}\end{array} \right )= \left ( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right ) \notin GL(2,\mathbb{R})$

So as it does not contain all it's limit points it's not closed so not compact?

Cheers Guys :)

Comment: What's the group operation on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @Mercy There is non, I'm considering it as a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the usual topology (and so the usual subspace topology)- sorry I didn't make that clear I'll edit it.

Comment: "I know we can do this by consider the mat $\det:GL(2,\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ and note that the image is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ which is open." This does not work: the image of a closed set under a continuous map can be open.

Comment: @Chris: True, but if we only wish to prove non-compatness it's enough.

Comment: $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ is in fact *dense* in $\mathbb R^4$, so very far from compact.

Comment: @ChrisEagle oh yeah but the inverse image of an open set is open, so that gives that $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is open?

Comment: @ChrisEagle I'm sorry your comment has confused me, how can we a continuous map in which the set $f(A)$ is open but $(A)$ is closed, does this not violate the definition of continuous?

Comment: No, it does not. Look again at the definition of continuous.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Sorry I'm a little confused, the set $A$ must be open right? So does this hold when it is both open and closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$GL(2,\Bbb R)$ appear to be far from being compact for the following reasons:

- It's not bounded, as if $A$ is invertible, so is $\lambda A$ for all real number $\lambda$.
- It's not closed as noted in the OP, as $k^{-1}I_2$ (after identification $(k^{-1},0,0,k^{-1})$ converges to $(0,0,0,0)$ which is not invertible). Actually, $GL(2,\Bbb R)$ appears to be an open strict subset of $\Bbb R^4$.